# Requests GET возвращает код 403

Tags: python, requests, http-status-code-403

При попытке выполнения `GET` запроса к сайту https://www.wine-searcher.com/ возвращается `http`-код [403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403), в чем может быть проблема?

```
import requests

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
           'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0'
}

def wine_parse(url, headers):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(url, headers=headers)
    print(request)

url = 'https://www.wine-searcher.com/'
wine_parse(url, headers)
```

Comment: Proxy менял, не помогло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У сервера включена `CSP`-директива [upgrade-insecure-requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Upgrade-Insecure-Requests). Сообщи серверу в запросе, что не против апгрейда с `http` на `https`:

```
headers = {
    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}
```